# AngularJS - Can't remove numbers after decimal point

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json

Im pulling in a JSON value from and API call that is returning this date and time value:

```
2016-07-25 10:50:14.000
```

Im trying to remove the last 3 zeros but don't know how to do this.

I have tried:

```
<div class="createdOn">Created On: {{ details['Created At'] | number:2 }} </div>
```

But that displays nothing at all. Is there a way for me to use jQuery to grab that text and then remove the zeros at the end?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your date is in fact a string. So in angular that should work :

```
 <div class="createdOn">Created On: {{ details['Created At'] | limitTo:19 }}</div>
```

For ref : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo

Like str point it, you can too treat it like a date (your format permit it and it's perhaps a better solution):

```
{{ details['Created At'] | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss' }}
```

Reference: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Comment: @agon024 Just because it works does not mean it is a good solution.

Comment: @str. Your solution is better. But after it depends of what he want to do.

Comment: @str your solution did not work. The date and time stayed the same.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is http://momentjs.com/ you can assign your formats easily.